# List of CDN domains

Tags: dns, cdn

Is there some place when we can see a list of most popular CDN domains?

I use OpenDNS together with TreeWalk, and I'd like to add rules to TreeWalk to use my ISP DNS for CDN.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the source code of webpagetest.org. They have a complete list of CDN domains https://github.com/WPO-Foundation/webpagetest/blob/master/agent/wpthook/cdn.h